# Tshark exit codes

Tags: wireshark, exit-code, tshark, return-code

I'm currently working with tshark using python subprocess and I want to handle errors in the child process currently.

I can get the sub-process exit code via python's subproccess 'returncode' field, but I can't fined any documentation of tshark exit codes.

I already figured out that 0 means success (no surprise) and 2 means corrupt or unsupported file.
But where there is 0 and 2 there is usually a 1, and there should be more codes.

Does anyone know were I can fined a list of thsark's possible error codes and causes?

Answer (score 1):

Ages ago, I seem to remember somebody suggesting an exit status of 1 for command-line syntax errors and 2 for other errors, and I've followed that convention for a lot of code I've written.

So 1 would be returned if you gave an invalid command-line flag or an invalid capture or display filter or something such as that, and 2 would be returned if it couldn't open a capture device or capture file.

Comment: Welp. And how would you figure out what's the actual issue in a script? It seems parsing stderr and relying on text messages is nearly the only option...